# Google drive API in AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, aws-lambda

I want to use Google Drive API in AWS Lambda using Node.JS. Is there any Google drive library for this which can allow me to copy file from one folder and paste it into another in AWS Lambda function without using oAuth as I am not sure if oAuth would be supported on AWS lambda.

I came across this: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/master/samples/drive

but it doesn't look like it would work in AWS as it is using oAuth.

**Edit:** I am only going to access my account.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, did u finally found a working solution?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is entirely possible.  I would [Start Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) and also look at the examples [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/master/samples/drive).  The fact that it's using oAuth doesn't prevent it from working in AWS or a lambda.  You will need to setup and application in google to be allowed to oAuth against it, and information about that can be found [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth).